# Using PKCS 11 token for SSL Handshake

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, pkcs#11

I try to establish a SSL Client authentication with a PKCS#11 Card under Android. I can read the Certificate fine, but sadly i can't extract the private key, so i can't use it to create my KeyStore. Since i don't get any Lib from the vendor and can't use the SUN implementation of PKCS11, since that is not supported by android, i guess i have to override the SSLContext to change the way it handles the signing process, so i can encrypt and decrypt the Handshake via the card?

Also i can't use the full PKCS11 API i got following methods:

> CK_RV C_GenerateKeyPair
>
> CK_RV C_GenerateRandom
>
> CK_RV C_Decrypt
>
> CK_RV C_Sign
>
> CK_RV C_Encrypt

The login to the Card is handled beforehand by a different Software, so i already have access.

So basically two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to handle the authentification without access
   to the private key?
2. What or Where do i have to override to handle the SSL signing via the card?

Comment: What about a custom KeyStoreSpi implementation that uses your PKCS#11 card?

Comment: That's what i started doing till i realized, with a custom KeyStore i will still need a private key, don't i?

Comment: Look into the sources of [SunPKCS11](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/pkcs11/SunPKCS11.java) they implement not only the KeyStore, but also a PKCS11 version of the PrivateKey (just a reference to the on-card key), Cipher and so on. Looks like this is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9220265/207421: see especially the answer recommending SpongyCastle.

Comment: @Robert will look into the code even so i'm confused how they will be able to get a private key, which can't be accessed, thats not the case woth all cards.

Comment: @EJP no its not a duplicate it's a followup question, basicly what im asking for is pointers where to start with that answer.

Comment: Eh, old question. You could solve this by calling the card through the ISO 7816 interface itself through the NFC API, but it would require you to create a custom provider (which does not have to be signed for Android) that contains a custom `KeyStoreSpi`, `PrivateKey` and `SignatureSpi`. Tough job, but it can be done.

Comment: You cannot ust SunPKCS11 by adding it to JDK? Copy `sunpkcs11.jar` to the `%JAVA_HOME%/ext/lib` and edit the "Installed JRE" in Eclipse, I am using it like this. Although I downloaded a random version of this jar, not knowing which is the proper to get.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to handle the authentification without access to the private key?

There is *no* way to handle the authentication without access to the private key.

> What or Where do i have to override to handle the SSL signing via the card?

Android must provide some form of PKCS#11 handler surely? If not, there is a free one by IAIK you can build yourself, I did it years ago for AIX.

Comment: "There is no way to handle the authentication without access to the private key."
I Kinda have access to the private key, but only over the decrypt and sign function of the API, so it seems i have to handle that myself and override something in the SSL progress

Comment: "Android must provide some form of PKCS#11 handler surely? If not, there is a free one by IAIK you can build yourself, I did it years ago for AIX."
No Android doesnt provide anything PKCS11 related for what reason ever. The IAIK provider is not free of charge only the wrapper, which i dont need since im using JNI to achieve what the wrapper does(Accessing the API)

Comment: You contradict yourself. PKCS#11 allows to use a private key that is on-card (usable but not accessible) but in your first sentence you say that this is impossible because you don't have access to the private key.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is, that i can work with the privatkey, using the cards API (Encrypt, decrypt, sign) but i can't extract it into my android app to use it with the SSLContext and or KeyStore.